# Scrape and iterate over html table without classes

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I'm building a webscraper with nodejs and pupeteer.
Everthing works fine, but now im stuck on how to get structured data from a table without classes. Here's an example:

I don't know how to iterate thru the table and extract the data in json format which should like this:

```
<table class="tableclass">
   <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <b>
        <strong>
        <span>A</span></strong> &amp; B <strong><span>C</span></strong>Name</b>
     </td>
     <td >
        Street No<br>
        Zip City
     </td>
     <td >
        <a href="https://www.google.de/maps/place/..." target="_blank">Map</a> | <a href="http://www.websiteA.de" target="_blank">Website</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <b>
        <strong>
        <span>A</span></strong> &amp; B <strong><span>C</span></strong>Name</b>
     </td>
     <td >
        Street No<br>
        Zip City
     </td>
     <td >
        <a href="https://www.google.de/maps/place/..." target="_blank">Map</a> | <a href="http://www.websiteB.de" target="_blank">Website</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>


Obj ={
   "content":[
      {
         "name":"A&B C Name",
         "adress":[
            "Street No",
            "Zip",
            "City"
         ],
         "link":"http://www.websiteB.de"
      },
   ]
}
```

Comment: [ask] Please mention what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the table have a consistent structure in each case? If so, you just need to figure out how to get to each element from the root of of table. For instance, to get the name, assuming that the above table structure is the same for all tables:

```
const table = document.querySelector('.tableclass')
Obj ={
   "content":[
      {
         "name": table.querySelectorAll('tr')[0].querySelectorAll('td')[0].innerText;
          ....
   ]
}
```

Here, I get the table element I am interested in using `document.querySelector('.tableclass')` - which will return the first instance of `.tableclass` on the page. If you have multiple, you will have to use `document.querySelectorAll` and perform these operations on each table in a for-loop.

Then, I use the querySelector but limited to this table, and I grab the first  element, because that's where the name is. (`table.querySelectorAll('tr')[0]`). Here I could have just used (`table.querySelector('tr')`) as I wanted the first element, but this is just to show you how you can access any of the s by their index. Finally, following the same logic, I need to select the first  element as that is the element that contains all the 'name' text, then I just use its .innerText attribute to extract the text.

`innerText` will be your friend here - just traverse the DOM nodes using node.querySelector until you get to one that contains all the text you want and no more, then get the `.innerText` attribute on that node. If the table has consistent structure, you should just be able to figure this out for one table and it should work on all of them.

Comment: Thanks! Working well so far. Now I just have some problems to geht the for Loop working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    var i = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const table = document.querySelector('#tableclass');      
        let dealer = table.querySelectorAll('tr')[i].querySelectorAll('td')[0].innerText;
        let adress = table.querySelectorAll('tr')[i].querySelectorAll('td')[1].innerText;
        let link = table.querySelectorAll('tr')[i].querySelectorAll('td')[2].querySelectorAll('a')[1].getAttribute("href");
        return {
            dealer,
            adress,
            link
          }
      }
```

I want to loop thru the table/ each row in it. I know this is wrong, but I don't know how to loop in this case. Thanks for help!

Comment: The easiest way is to actually use a forEach loop over the NodeList returned by `document.querySelectorAll`
`document.querySelectorAll('.tableclass').forEach((tableElem) => { /* do something with each table element here */ })
`